# filesystem shared by multiprecoesses with multithreads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, filesystems, multiprocessing

here is the case:

```
I am talking about general linux concurrent programming environment

Definition: 
  Node: a machine with a processor.
  file system: can be accessed both locally and remotely. 
 it includes large set of files varied in random size.      

Node I: Process A with multithreads access A's file system, operations include 
read and write. Process B, similar to A. Think about more similar processes 
C,D,etc. 

Then, thinking about scaling. The same FS system is located on a separate node. 
Operated by processes E,F,G etc on node II, and processes A,B,C,D on Node I.
thinking about similar node III,IV,V, etc.
```

This is both a practical and interview question. Here is my solution:

```
I can use mutex and signal resolve multi reader and writer of the same 
file within a process. And also using IPC resolve multiprocesses 
communication and synchronization.
the code could work very well for single node multiprocesses. 

But, when dealing with multi node. We need similar but more 
 complicated mechanism to detect are there any node 
 writting on the FS, if yes, wait; otherwise, access  
writting mutex and write, then notify waiting guys.
```

After more thinking, follows is my idea:

```
From the point of a NFS, we define file lock of course based on file. 
My target is:
at each moment,there is only one writer write the file, 
there can be more than one reader read the file. 
Then, all the processes on different nodes are the same. 
 they should have their own mechanism to acquire either read or write lock, 
 of course, dealing with connection, failures and retries.
```

I am wondering if there is some prototype for such kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

I assume "node" means "network node", i.e. an entity running its own copy of the operating system. It could be an actual machine or a virtual machine.

The question is pretty badly worded, honestly. It's not really clear what is being asked; I could assume that they're not asking about inter-node synchronization or locking.

So you're good on the first part: mutexes between threads, IPC semaphores between processes on the same machine.

If you want to handle interactions between separate nodes, first you need to have a networked filesystem, such as NFS or CIFS. Second, you need *file locks* (or *lock files*) to manage access to shared files. File locks can also be used at the other levels, inter-thread and inter-process, though they're not as straightforward as mutexes and semaphores.

You could also build up a synchronization system from sockets, but that requires each node to have a socket to each other node, which means N^2 sockets with possible race conditions, or a central clearinghouse node, which becomes a single point of failure.

Comment: I think inter-node synchronization could be one solution to multiple nodes access shared NFS. Like, one consumer node might suspend its read if there is no update since last read. And another consumer might resume this node after updating the file. I think the solution is sort of complicated.

Comment: If you have producers and consumers communicating, you might want to look at some form of [Message-Passing Interface (MPI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) (e.g. [MPICH](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/mpi/)).